# How to combine array that has the same values in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the following array:

```
0: {x: "/", y: 8}
1: {x: "/a", y: 7}
2: {x: "/a", y: 2}
3: {x: "/", y: 1}
```

How can I turn that into:

```
0: {x: "/", y: 9}
1: {x: "/a", y: 9}
```

Where the same values of X have their Y value added on.

It should only look for the same values of `X`, if they are the same it combines them and adds their `Y` together.

Comment: That's an array of objects, to be clear, not *really* a 2D array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) with an object to store the values for each `x`.

```js
let arr = [{x: "/", y: 8},{x: "/a", y: 7},{x: "/a", y: 2},{x: "/", y: 1}];
let res = Object.values(arr.reduce((acc,{x,y})=>{
  (acc[x] = acc[x] || {x, y:0}).y += y;
  return acc;
}, {}));
console.log(res);
```